# Question about distance between points in a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E \subset \mathbb R^k.$ Assume $E$ is not closed. Then it has a limit point $x_0 \in \mathbb R^k$ with $x_0 \not \in E.$ We can construct an infinite subset $S$ of $E$ whose only limit point is $x_0,$ so it has no limit point in $E.$ **For every $r > 0,$ there is a point $x \in E$ such that $|x − x_0| < r,$ so for every $n \in \mathbb N,$ there is some $x_n \in E$ with** $|x_n − x_0 | < \frac1n .$ Let $S = \{x_n | n \in \mathbb N\},$ so $S \subset E.$

I have questions about the part in bold of the quote above.

> For every $r > 0,$ there is a point $x \in E$ such that $|x − x_0| < r,$

Where does this assertion come from? Is it by density of $\mathbb Q \in \mathbb R?$ If not, how do we know this?

> so for every $n \in \mathbb N,$ there is some $x_n \in E$ with $|x_n − x_0 | < \frac1n$

How does it follow from the statement above? Is it because the above statement is true for all $r > 0,$ we simply let $r = \frac1n?$ If not, then how does it follow?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of limit point?

Comment: @mfl,  point $p$ is a limit point of $E \subset X \ (X $ is a metric space) every neighborhood of $p$ contains at least one point of $E$ other than possibly itself.

Comment: So if $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ then given the neighbourhood $B(x_0,r)$ of $x_0$ there exists a point $x\in E$ such that $x\in B(x_0,r).$ Thus $d(x,x_0)<r.$

Comment: @mfl, ok I see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement follows from the fact that $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$.

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and put $r=1/n$. By the first statement there is $x \in E$ with $|x-x_0|<r$. Put $x_n=x$.